# Android setPixels returning black color

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I have the following functions:

```
private void clearScreen(int color)
{
    fOffscreenImage.eraseColor(color);
}

private void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int color)
{
    for(;x<width;x++)
    {
        for(;y<height;y++)
        {
            buffer[x+y*PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH] = color;
        }
    }
}

private void drawBuffer()
{
    fOffscreenImage.setPixels(buffer,0,PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH,0,0,PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH,PROJECTIONPLANEHEIGHT);
}
```

Both functions draw to a bitmap, first is by eraseColor, which works fine, and second is by setPixels, which always returns black. I'm writing the image to a quad displayed with OpenGL. As color input I tried default colors (Color.BLUE) and Color.argb.
getPixel does return the correct output of the colors in question.

A by pixel call to setPixel would not work either, it would ignore the job.

I'm tried with Android 2.1 and 2.3.

Any suggestions on this would be great..

Comment: try  

buffer[x+y*PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH] = Color.argb(#ffff0000);

and post back if the complete image is red (just to eliminate some problems)

Comment: buffer[x+y*PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH] = 0xffff0000; returned a black screen as well

Comment: Why are you using setPixel? Are you trying to texutre made a quad or just colour it?

Comment: It's for a raycaster. Displaying on a quad and then texturing it circumvents the low performance barrier of canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int color)
{
    width += x;
    height += y;
    for(;x<width;x++)
    {
        for(;y<height;y++)
        {
            buffer[x+y*PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH] = color;
        }
    }
}
```

should be

```
private void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int color)
{
    width += x;
    height += y;
    for(int y2 = y;y2<height;y2++)
    {
        for(int x2 = x;x2<width;x2++)
        {
            buffer[x2+y2*PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH] = color;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced part of the raycaster with the following fillRect code, and it shows white lines on the appropriate places now!
Now just to find out other colors as well :)

```
private void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int color)
{
    width += x;
    height += y;
    for(;x<width;x++)
    {
        for(;y<height;y++)
        {
            if (x+y*PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH < PROJECTIONPLANEHEIGHT*PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH)
                buffer[x+y*PROJECTIONPLANEWIDTH] = color;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by not using a setPixel, but instead using canvas to draw to the bitmap. However it's dead slow..